# Tensorflow - calling a model inside a GradientTape scope VS calling it inside a loss function

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, tensorflow, keras

Is there a difference in the gradient computation between the two code snippets ...

Code 1:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

     output_A = model_A(input)
     output_B = model_B(input)

     loss = loss_fn(output_A, output_B, true_output_A, true_output_B)

grads = tape.gradient(loss, model_A.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_A.trainable_variables))

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSE = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

def loss_fn(output_A, output_B, true_output_A, true_output_B)

     loss = MSE(output_A, true_output_A) + MSE(output_B, true_output_B)

     return loss
```

Code 2:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

     output_A = model_A(input)

     loss = loss_fn(output_A, model_B, input, true_output_A, true_output_B)

grads = tape.gradient(loss, model_A.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_A.trainable_variables))

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSE = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

def loss_fn(output_A, model_B, input, true_output_A, true_output_B)

     output_B = model_B(input)
     
     loss = MSE(output_A, true_output_A) + MSE(output_B, true_output_B)

     return loss
```

`output_A` and `output_B` are related using a mathematical equation .. I would like `model_A` to learn how to generate `output_A` using the way `model_B` generates `output_B` ..

I hope that makes sense ...

Comment: This is the only official Tensorflow tutorial where they call the Model inside the Loss function .. but this doesn't seem to work in my case https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough